# Magento 2.4.3 currency symbol not showing on product,cart and checkout page

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, cart, currency

I have just setup fresh Magento 2.4.3 on the VPS server and noticed that the Currency symbol not showing on my website, Any help is highly appreciated.
Url - https://stagingsgwdirect.com

https://prnt.sc/1uzijjq
https://prnt.sc/1uzimv4
https://prnt.sc/1uziqa4

Thanks In advance

Comment: Its a bug in Magento 2.4.3. There is a temp fix for it. I'll post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

Its a bug in 2.4.3:

src\vendor\magento\module-directory\Model\Currency.php

Comment out these lines:

```
if ($this->canUseNumberFormatter($options)) {
    return $this->formatCurrency($price, $options);
}
```

Then:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then do full re-index.

Editing core is bad, but deploying a fix will take a full day. Look into [Preferences](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html)

Original issue in Github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856

Comment: Thanks, Working fine for me.

Comment: @SonuKumar please accept as an answer, thanks!

Comment: @SonuKumar might as well wait for 2.4.3-p1 as it's being released on Tuesday next week.

Comment: @SonuKumar please accept my answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

We were running into this issue on m2.4.3 and 2.4.5.

Viewing the screenshots on Safari's Timeline feature on Inspect Element, I could see when the currency symbol disappears.
You can see just before the symbol disappears that there are two .js scripts running. Filtering by "price" results in price-box.js line 148, which is located in:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js`

I copied this file into our theme: `<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js`

and where it said:

```
_.each(this.cache.displayprices, function (price, pricecode) {
```

I removed the ".cache" from the code and it now runs perfectly. eg:

```
_.each(this.displayprices, function (price, pricecode) {
```

Haven't seen any dramatic slowdown in page load speed